# Azure Service Fabric deployment error: The port '-1' specified on your connection endpoint does not match the default Client Connection Endpoint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I get the following error in the detailed logs when deploying via Azure DevOps:

> The port '-1' specified on your connection endpoint does not match the
>   default Client Connection Endpoint of '19000'. This might have caused
>   cluster communication failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put the management endpoint port (19000 by default) to the Service Fabric connection in the release pipeline :

> tcp://clustername.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000

Without specifying the port, you get the above error.